# Passing arrays from php to header, href not at full length

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a page that takes in customer details and after submit is pressed the data is sent to a php function in a separate file to validate. If the data entered is incorrect, a box pops up with details on the error. The function should return a href to put into an `<a>` tag so that the customer can try again. This href contains the details they entered as an array. I have echoed out this href at various stages and it works fine. However when clicking on the link it doesn't insert the whole array in the URL.

The conversion is done by json_encode and decode

The IF statement where the array is converted to a string:

```
if($check == 'false' and $checkNO == 1){
            //if there are empty fields
            echo "<div class='head'>Failed to place order <br><br></div>";
            echo $error['empty'];
            $pass_details = json_encode($details);
            return "order_form.php?main_pkey=$stockID&details=$pass_details";
        }elseif($check == 'false' and $checkNO == 2){
            //if the fieled are filled in incorrectly
            echo "<div class='head'>Failed to place order <br><br></div>";
            foreach($error as $value){
                echo $value;
            }
            $pass_details = json_encode($details);
            return "order_form.php?main_pkey=$stockID&details=$pass_details";
        }elseif($check == 'true'){
            //convert array to string so that it can be passed to the confirm page in the headder 
            $pass_details = json_encode($details);
            //direct to confirm
            header("Location: confirm.php?main_pkey=$stockID&details=$pass_details");
        }
```

The order form page where the string is converted back into an array:

```
if(isset($_GET['details'])){
    $details = json_decode($_GET['details'], true);
}else{
    $details = array("title" => "", "fname" => "", "sname" => "", "address1" => "", "address2" => "", "post" => "", "email" => "", "quantity" => "", "comment" => "");
}

if (isset($_POST["order_form"])){
    echo '<div id="openModal" class="modalbg">
            <div class="dialog">';
                $href = validateorderform($stockID);
                echo '<a href=' . $href . ' title="Close" class="close"><x>X</x></a>
                </div>
    </div>';
}
```

this is what appears in the address bar once 'x' is pressed:

```
order_form.php?main_pkey=1&details={"title":"Mr","fname":"data
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to pass JSON string over the URL as some characters may not be accepted by the web app (or the browser?). Use a function that encodes the array into the query string.

Have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php